# jQuery Infinite Scroll - possible to reset page count?

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm using this plugin https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll to make an endless page.

However I have some links on the site which replace the content in the infinite scroll panes. I've managed to have it update the path that infinite scroll calls however it continues it's pagination from where the origin set of items left off.

i.e. if you scroll 7 'pages' then change the items by clicking a link it loads page 1 then the infinite scroll plugin loads page 8 next.

I've tried lots of variations of

```
$(".infinite-scroll-container").infiniteScroll().currPage = 1;
```

and

```
$(".infinite-scroll-container").options.state.currPage = 1;
```

I'm not sure how I would tell the Infinite Scroll plugin to reset it's page counter. I guess my ideal solution is being able to modify or create a function to modify it's internal page counter?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Did you try unbinding and then binding again with new parameters? such as with `currPage=1`

Comment: binding or using it's init parameters from the original domready again seems to stop it loading anything :s just using the unbind and bind methods doesn't reset the counter :/

Comment: Well this might be of help. check out http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/ check `Custom trigger, non-automatic. Twitter-style` section if you haven't already done so. Otherwise I suggest you post some sample code here using JSFiddle so that we can debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a public method to the plugin which resets the page counter. I've posted it below. Turns out it was rather simple..

```
resetpage: function(){
    this.options.state.currPage = 1;
},
```